# How can I return a json of files with python flask-restfull?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to send two files in a json object with flask restfull and send_file.

When I try to access the json object on client side i get this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable
```

This is what i do i my flask app:

```
class Download(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            return {"file1" : send_file('uploads/kode.png'), "file2" : send_file('uploads/kode.png')}, 200
        except:
            return {"message" : "File not found!"}, 404
```

How can I return a json of files?

Comment: What is "a json of files"? What exactly do you expect the user to receive as a response with the code in your question?

Comment: If I do the same thing with only one file without wrapping the send_file() in {}, I can access that file on the front end with java script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I do the same thing with only one file without wrapping the send_file() in {}, I can access that file on the front end with java script.

You mean like:

```
return send_file('path/to/file.png')
```

That works, because Flask's `send_file` function actually returns a `Response` object.

This is also valid code [(as of flask version `1.1.0`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917715/2052575):

```
return {"message" : "File not found!"}, 404
```

Here you're returning a dictionary with the key `'message'` and value `'File not found!'`.  Flask will turn this into a `Response` object, with a status code of `404`.

That dictionary is jsonified automatically [(as of flask version `1.1.0`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917715/2052575).

When you try to return this:

```
return {"file1" : send_file('uploads/kode.png')}, 200
```

The `Response` object returned by `send_file` is then jsonified, hence the exception:

> `TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable`

---

The obvious way to make this work is that the frontend should make a separate request to the server for each image, passing some kind of ID which the Flask route function should then [obtain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/2052575) and use to work out the filepath, then ultimately: `return sendfile(filepath)`.

If you really want to send several images in one JSON response, you could look at [base64 encoding the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141121/2052575) and making a data_uri string which can be JSON serialized.  However unless you really need that data to be passed as JSON, the former option is probably the go-to.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Why would I not use base64 encoding? Api calls from the frontend are costly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your except is too broad. but to get a json object back, import json and its object.json()

```
import json
try:
    return file.json()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

or your can import the json library from flask

```
from flask import jsonify
def myMethod():
    ....
    response = jsonify(data)
    response.status_code = 200 # or 400 or whatever
    return response
```